# is there an new version of mozart/oz?

Tags: oz, mozart

Would like to know if there is a new version of mozart/oz currently it is 1.4. That was in 2008. There has to have been progress.

Comment: -1 Usefulness of question and answer degrade with time, what was once new becomes old with time. BTW, Mozart2 is out. http://mozart.github.io/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, 1.5.0 appears to be available here: http://gforge.info.ucl.ac.be/projects/mozart/ although the tags from [the download page](http://gforge.info.ucl.ac.be/frs/?group_id=17) call it 1.4.99.

I'm not sure why you believe that *"there has to have been progress"*; projects get abandoned or shelved all the time. Sometimes, a mature project is sufficiently "done" that no one is interested in working on it any more.

Comment: Phrogz - Thanks for the response.